# Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=null} to activity {}: java.lang.NullPointerException: uri

Tags: android, android-intent, onactivityresult, mediastore

I currently have an issue Failure delivering result ResultInfo. Surprisingly, it works until Android 9 (API 28), this NullPointerExceptions occur with Android 10(API29). The issued intent is within the same class. The NullPointerExceptions raises calling getBitmap as Intent data is null!

Error Message:

`java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=null} to activity {de.janlo.recyclergridview/de.janlo.recyclergridview.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: uri`

Here is the code:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode,
                                int resultCode,
                                Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Log.e(TAG, "reqCode = " + requestCode);
    Log.e(TAG, "resultCode = " + resultCode);

    if (requestCode == IMAGE_CAPTURE) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            try {
                //Bitmap b1 = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
                Bitmap b1 = MediaStore.Images.Media
                        .getBitmap(
                                getContentResolver(), imageUri);
                String dateTaken = MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN;
                String dateModified = MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_MODIFIED;
```